# Need help centering my cta

Tags: html, css, center, margin

Ok, so i cant seem to center my call to action, any ideas why its stuck to the left? keep in mind that im using bootstrap and sass

```
    <div class="jumbotron">
      <nav>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <ul>
              <li class="p_nav">Home</li>
              <li class="p_nav">About</li>
              <li class="p_nav">Work</li>
              <li class="p_nav">Contact</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
      <div class="container">
        <h1>Name</h1>
        <p class="p_jumbo">secondary text</p>
        <div class="cta">Learn more</div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

and the css. Do i need a parrent with a position tag maybe?

```
.jumbotron {
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: url("/img/jumbobg.png");
  background-size: cover; }

nav ul {
  list-style: none; }
  nav ul li {
    display: inline;
    float: right;
    margin: 20px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px; }

.cta {
  border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
  border-radius: 100px;
  font-family: Avenir-Light;
  font-size: 20.25px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto; }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `margin: 0 auto` isn't working because of `inline-block` display.
remove this line and give your cta a width.

```
.cta {
    border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
    border-radius: 100px;
    font-family: Avenir-Light;
    font-size: 20.25px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    /* display: inline-block; */
    padding: 10px 20px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 200px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this **first**

```
<div class="jumbotron">
  <nav>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <ul>
          <li class="p_nav">Home</li>
          <li class="p_nav">About</li>
          <li class="p_nav">Work</li>
          <li class="p_nav">Contact</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Name</h1>
    <p class="p_jumbo">secondary text</p>
    <div class="cta center-block">Learn more</div>
  </div>
</div>`
```

**second options** :- inside css add

```
width: 50%;
margin: 0 auto;
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution will be to remove `display: inline-block` from the `.cta` element. This will cause the CTA to center.

```css
.jumbotron {
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: url("/img/jumbobg.png");
  background-size: cover; }

nav ul {
  list-style: none; }
  nav ul li {
    display: inline;
    float: right;
    margin: 20px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px; }

.cta {
  border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
  border-radius: 100px;
  font-family: Avenir-Light;
  font-size: 20.25px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto; }
```

```html
<div class="jumbotron">
      <nav>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <ul>
              <li class="p_nav">Home</li>
              <li class="p_nav">About</li>
              <li class="p_nav">Work</li>
              <li class="p_nav">Contact</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
      <div class="container">
        <h1>Name</h1>
        <p class="p_jumbo">secondary text</p>
        <div class="cta">Learn more</div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Here's a [working JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/brettdewoody/dsLpsch6/)